# Debug a self signed android app? (Need it for facebook integration)

Tags: android, debugging, facebook, signing

When hitting the "debug"-button in eclipse my App gets signed by a debug key form android which is stored in the file "debug.keystore".

Now I am implementing the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) which forces me to use a signed app for the Single SignOn feature. That way I need to generate the hash of my companies keystore and store the one in our facebook developer account.

I know how to sign an app through the wizard in Eclipse (over the AndroidManifest.xml). How to debug such a signed app?

Can I change the debug key somehow and set up our companies key as debug key? Or how should I go? Right now I can get FB working only by signing and installing my app on a device. I already tried to generate a hash of the debug key with no luck...

Comment: Any chance you can do debugging the primitive way, via progress/"oops" messages in logcat?

Comment: Are you setting the android:debuggable=true?

Comment: @blindstuff: Yes. Although eclipse told me, that its not a good idea. But how to debug it then? 

For developing now I just use not Single SignOn (uninstall the FB app from the test device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend setting your companies key as your debug key, but you can do that by replacing the Eclipse debug keystore file, named debug.keystore. You can find its location on your OS by reading through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode).

A better solution would be to generate the hash of the debug key - follow the instructions given on the official SDK for Android page, and make sure you mention the correct keystore file, and the alias "androiddebugkey". The password is always "android".

Comment: Yes, I tried "the better solution" with no luck. That was the command to generate the hash:        keytool -exportcert -alias android -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e    I just recognize that I may have chosen the wrong alias. Regarding to the link u posted above I have to use "androiddebugkey" instead of "android". Will try that later some time

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry for saying "no alias" - I realized the alias was androiddebugkey. I realized that when I was doing some final testing of my app. The password of that alias is android. It worked fine for me !

Comment: WORKS! With the right alias... keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e

Comment: If you use Windows, open ssl might not be installed. This link might help you out: http://www.deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows/

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone wants to

> *change the debug key somehow and set up our companies key as debug key*

as the original poster asks, you can do so using keytool as so:

```
STORE_PASS=<pass_of_company_store>
ALIAS=<alias_of_key_in_company_store>
ALIAS_PASS=<pass_alias>
keytool -importkeystore -v -noprompt \
    -srckeystore /path/to/company/key -destkeystore debug.keystore \
    -srcstorepass $STORE_PASS -deststorepass android \
    -srcalias $ALIAS -destalias androiddebugkey \
    -srckeypass $ALIAS_PASS -destkeypass android
```

You can then replace your debug (perhaps ~/.android/debug.keystore) with the new one that this generates, and eclipse will happily use it to build apks that can be fully debugged and accepted by facebook.

**Note that you have to be very careful with this new debug.keystore. It cannot fall into the wrong hands or your app can easily be hijacked on the Google Play Store.**